OpenLayers how to load image from API, should probably await
I've got my own internal API that I wrote that returns images as a stream/physical file.  As I'm new to OpenLayers, I'm wondering how I could setup an image source to hit my own API and put that image into it's georeferenced location on top of an OSM layer.  I've got the coordinates from the calling app so I'll place those in an extent object.  I've been trying various examples I've seen online like this:
  function setSource() {
    const source = new ImageSource({
      url: url,
      crossOrigin: "",
      imageExtent: imageExtent,
      operationType: image,
    });
    imageLayer.setSource(source);

However, I think I need some kind of await here to await until that image is available over the URL of my API to this caller app.  My API just returns an image, it's not a WMS or tiling service.
Is ImageSource the right source for this?
I've been unable to get the image to draw trying various sources.  I'd think if I awaited the call it may work, but I haven't found an example outlining that yet.

I think I may have found the answer, it looks like I wasn't specifying the projection above, by adding that parameter, it appears that I now have this working...
